# RavenDb Select last comments

Tags: .net, ravendb

I have an entity Post which contains a child collection IList. Now I need to get 10 last comments to all posts. Here is my initial impelementation:

```
_documentSession.Query<Post>().SelectMany(x => x.Comments).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).Take(10).ToList();
```

But it doesn't work as RavenDb throws exception "SelectMany is not supported".

What is the right way to impelement it using RavenDb?

Comment: Would you mind posting your index here? I've been able to use Raven so far without using indexes, so I'd like to see how you solved this.

Comment: @BobHorn, my index was pretty similar to the one provided by Thomas Freudenberg

Comment: Those links are broken. I'll do some digging...

Comment: @BobHorn, here is what you are looking for: https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog/blob/master/RaccoonBlog.Web/Infrastructure/Indexes/PostComments_CreationDate.cs

Comment: Thanks, Idsa. Appreciate it...

Comment: @Bob you are using an index, it's just that RavenDB is creating it behind the scenes for you! See http://ayende.com/blog/4667/ravens-dynamic-queries

Comment: @Matt Right, I actually do understand that Raven queries against indexes, not documents. I guess what I really meant was that I haven't had to manually create indexes myself yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an index to accomplish that. The same problem was solved in [RacoonBlog](https://github.com/fitzchak/RaccoonBlog), see the [index definition](https://github.com/fitzchak/RaccoonBlog/blob/master/RaccoonBlog.Web/Infrastructure/Indexes/PostComments_CreationDate.cs).

Comment: Is an index the only way? I was able to accomplish this without an index by simply using Where(), OrderByDescending(), and Take(). As long as you're using IQueryable methods, and not IEnumerable, that should work. I worked through that issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931289/ravendb-orderbydescending-and-take-incorrect-results.

Comment: @Bob The list of comments is a property of `Post` documents, so you need an index to flatten them.